# Google Chrome Malware Warning when including images from image search API

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, google-image-search

I'm using Google and Bing image search APIs to provide a way for users of my web app to search for images to include in the documents they create in the app. A (rare?) problem I encountered today: a result from either Bing or Google (I'm going to assume Bing) caused the Google Chrome Malware detector to go off.
Is there any good way to avoid this that I'm not aware of, aside from only using the Google Image API (which is being deprecated!) since I assume they filter out results from sites they think contain malware?

There doesn't seem to be any performant way on my end to check these results before displaying them to prevent this error from occurring, and I'm very worried that any less savvy computer users will think my site is at fault (not to mention being unable to make the warning go away).

I guess I'm also making the assumption here that images from random Internet sites are okay to include in the page as long as they are returned by these APIs...I do copy them over to our own S3 account a few minutes after they are added to the document in case they are changed/removed on the external site...

EDIT: The result is indeed being included from the Bing API, and it is from thefatlossauthority.com.

I would prefer a solution based in Ruby, but given a general solution I'm more than willing to implement it myself.

Comment: A few possible solutions: use the Google Lookup API to check all domains before displaying images (although the image request itself already takes around 800ms, so I hesitate to add in any further remote API calls), proxy all image requests through a server so they appear to originate on my domain (seems bandwidth intensive and high maintenance)

Comment: Another possibility (just brainstorming): both Google and Bing provide thumbnails hosted by them for results. I could display thumbnails and then only include the "full size" image from the possibly "infected" domain if the user actually chooses to include that image. Should reduce the number of occurrences of this to some degree. In addition, I could display the lower resolution thumbnail in the document until I have copied the remote image to my S3 bucket, and then transparently replace the source with the higher quality image from S3.